# Remove grey lines in bar chart from pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

Is there a possibility to remove the grey inner axis lines in a bar chart from `pgfplots`?
Here is what my diagram currently looks like:
[image: diagram with inner axis lines]

And this is how I want it to be (I just deleted the lines with Paint):
[image: diagram without inner axis lines]

This is the code to generate the first example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xtick=data,
axis x line=bottom, 
axis y line=left,
enlargelimits=false,
ybar interval=.7,
]
\addplot coordinates {(1, 1000) (2,  2500) (3,  1000)(4, 1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An ad hoc solution: tell pgflots to draw some ticks outside the range only. The cleaner solution is to say `grid=none,` in the options, though.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xtick=data,
axis x line=bottom, 
axis y line=left,
enlargelimits=false,
ybar interval=.7,
minor xtick={},
grid=minor,
]
\addplot coordinates {(1, 1000) (2,  2500) (3,  1000)(4, 1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]